# Windows Forms Application GUI issues on Macbook M1 with Windows 11 via Parallels

Tags: c#, windows, forms, user-interface

I build a windows forms application on my windows desktop pc a few months ago.
Recently I bought a Macbook with a M1 ARM-CPU and installed the newest version of Parallels.

Today I launched this application on Visual Studio with Parallels and everything is working except the GUI of my application.

How it looks on my mac after compiling

[image: 1]

Everything is compressed and form fields and labels are overlapping. I have no idea what the reason is and how I can fix this. I tested it again on my Windows desktop-PC and everything is fine.

Has anyone an idea?

I tried to disable visual studio scaling and google a lot, but didnt find a solution.

Comment: This looks like a DPI problem. The lines aren't compressed, they're too close together for the font size. That's something that can be configured at the Windows level. `didnt find a solution.` that's because such problems occurred on windows a long time ago, when people switched to 1920x1080 displays. WinForms didn't have high DPI support at all at first, so it had similar issues. High DPI support was added to WPF, because it was assumed it would fully replace the legacy WinForms.

Comment: Which .NET version was used for the app? High DPI support was added in [.NET Framework 4.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and requires some configuration changes

Comment: The project is using .NET 6.0

Comment: Did you enable the High DPI settings? Tried changing the DPI settings in Windows, or the font size? You should check the [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) page too, because that's where things go wrong

Comment: Parallels should have settings how to scale the desktop of a VM. Here an older Knowledgebase entry showing that https://kb.parallels.com/123951 If changes here help you also have a problem in standard Windows installation if people uses scaled desktops(Zoom != 100%). And if you have designed the winforms app while your system wasn't running with 100% scaling (Visuals Studio will warn you then) you have to rework that as it presumably doesn't run then almost nowhere correctly.

Comment: My desktop is scaled 125% so your app is probably broken for me too not just Mac VMs

Comment: Could you please share the project/source code of the app in question?